# How to get bundles in iTunes API search results?

Tags: app-store, itunes, itunes-store, itunes-api

Tryed to use iTunes API, but pointed that there are no bundles in results.

For example, here are results in App Store: 
http://i61.tinypic.com/m6b92.jpg

And here are iTunes API results of this request https://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html:

1. TextGrabber + Translator...
2. FineScanner...
3. Словарь Lingvo...
4. Lingvo Live от ABBYY

How to get bundles in search?

Answer (score 0):

It's either undocumented or impossible to get information related to app bundles. I've been trying for a year but like video previews and in-app purchase data, it doesn't yet seem to be supported by the API.

I have tried querying the developer, querying individual apps in a bundle, and querying the bundle ID itself, but can't find any combination that works.

Answer (score -1):

I've had luck searching by the developer/publisher.  For instance, I was looking for the "Go Trilogy" bundle from Square-Enix.  Searching "Square Enix" brought up ALL of their releases AND currently offered bundles.  Hope this helps someone.